# Работа с русскими тэгами id3

Tags: php, mp3

Добрый вечер.

Мне стало необходимо чтение id3-тэгов средствами php. Нашёл где-то стандартный `php_id3.dll`, но он не хочет подключаться (php в упор не видит, у меня 5.6). Сторонний `getID3()` не понимает наших русских тэгов.

Как решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется библиотека [**getID3**](http://getid3.sourceforge.net), то там в файле `module.tag.id3v2.php` строку (начинается с 3119 строки)

```
static $TextEncodingNameLookup = array(
   0   => 'ISO-8859-1',
   1   => 'UTF-16',     
   2   => 'UTF-16BE',
   3   => 'UTF-8',
   255 => 'UTF-16BE'
);
```

заменить на

```
static $TextEncodingNameLookup = array(
    0   => 'cp1251',
    1   => 'UTF-16',
    2   => 'UTF-16BE',
    3   => 'UTF-8',
    255 => 'UTF-16BE'
);
```